# Etags caching on same resource uri possible?

Tags: http, caching, etag

My root url ('/') returns different content depending on whether you are logged in or not.

Are etags still possible for this url? Would it be easier to just host the logged in content on a different url?

Answer (score 2):

You can deliver the resource with two distinct `ETags`. A request can have both tags in the  [`If-None-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26). You can then decide if the cached entity is valid and tell the client which one to show:

> If any of the entity tags match [..] then the server MUST NOT perform the requested method [..]. Instead, if the request method was GET or HEAD, the server SHOULD respond with a 304 (Not Modified) response, including the cache- related header fields (particularly ETag) of one of the entities that matched.